# GetService method of Package is returning null in vs2017 extension

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating a visual studio 2017 extension in C# for pending changes. I got reference from [here](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2015/MZ2015007.aspx).
I am trying to get the instance via GetService method.
But everytime I am getting teamExplorer as null.

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer teamExplorer;

            teamExplorer = base.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer))
               as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer;
```

Can someone please help me in this ? How can I get the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get the instance via GetService method. But everytime
>   I am getting teamExplorer as null.

The method is too old you cannot get what you want by using `GetService()` method. You can try my steps to realize it which l have tested successfully.

1) Reference the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll` under the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\xxxxx\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`.

Note: you should reference the related DLL in this folder and these APIs are for Visual Studio 2017.

2) change to use these codes:

```
    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer teamExplorer;

    teamExplorer= Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer))

    as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer;
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks, That method worked. But I am facing same issue with GetExtensibilityService method. While getting the instance of IPendingChanges it is returning null.pendingChangesExt = teamExplorerPage.GetExtensibilityService(
               typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.Extensibility.IPendingChangesExt))
               as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.Extensibility.IPendingChangesExt; Is this GetExtensibilityService method deprecated as well ? If so which method to use for that purpose ?

Comment: If so, first, make sure that you have import the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll` in the same folder of VS2017. Besides, if you debug this method when you commit the changes and also get `null`, you can try to change the method to get the teamExplorerPage------- `teamExplorerPage = teamExplorer.NavigateToPage(new Guid(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.TeamExplorerPageIds.PendingChanges),null);`.